# How to avoid to rewrite attributes with AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, age INT);
```

Is there a simpler method than rewriting the attributes of the column like that ?

```
INSERT INTO Person (age) VALUES (18);
```

I know that for the DEFAULT values there is the keyword DEFAULT, but is there a similar one for AUTO_INCREMENT? I work with pretty long tables and I don't want to rewrite all the column names each time I make an INSERT.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html says:

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers.

So any of the following will work:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (0, 18);
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (NULL, 18);
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (DEFAULT, 18);
```

However, it's considered good practice to list all columns explicitly when you write any INSERT statement. If someone changes the order of columns in the table, your VALUES might not get inserted into the right columns unless you list the column names explicitly. Also if someone adds or drops a column.